# UWP Unit Tests Don't Show Up in Rider

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, mstest, rider, dotcover

I have a solution with two unit testing projects. One is for .NET and the other is for UWP. The .NET Framework and .NET Core tests show up in Rider but the UWP tests don't show up. They show up in Visual Studio. You can see the project [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/tree/develop/src/Usb.Net.UWP.Sample). It appears that dotCover is supposed to [support UWP](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Profiling_Guidelines__Windows_Store_Applications.html). I assume that Rider uses the same engine. Also, I opened dotCover and found my app unit testing app among the packages but it doesn't pick up any of the tests either. I'm using MS Test but can switch if need be.

This is what I see in dotCover:
[image]

Does Rider support UWP for unit testing? If not, can I do this with dotCover? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, even ReSharper does not support discovering UWP tests in Visual Studio 2019 due to a lack of API. That's why it does not work in Rider as well.

However, we've implemented our own test runner to run UWP tests https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-473827, and it will be available in upcoming releases in both ReSharper and Rider.